# Parameterise a line represented by n points

Tags: vectors, parametrization, programming

I'm trying to write a program where I draw points at constant increments, regardless of how curvy a road is. For example, a straight line of length 10 and increment 2 would have 5 points spaced 2 meters away from each other, and would be as simple as adding 2 to the value of the previous point. However it gets a lot more complex when dealing with lines that aren't straight.

Let's say I have n points which represent a line. Is it possible to parameterise it in say, Cartesian coordinates, so that I can find any point on that line simply by passing in an independent variable?
For example, say I have a line made up of n points, all connected by line segments. Is there a way I can find a point on any of those lines through a parameterised vector? For example, a circle with equation x^2+y^2 = 4 can be parameterised as r(theta) = (2cos(theta) , 2sin(theta). Is there a way to do something similar with the image below, with the first point n = 0 being used as the reference point.
[Line made up of n points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HPC6.png)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can parameterize that but the greater the number of segments the uglier the parameterization becomes because of the cases in the definition.

For a line segment between two points $p, q$ we parametrize the segment by $$f(t)=(1-t)p + tq$$ where $t\in [0,1]$.

If we want to add another point $r$ to get two line segments: one between $p$ and $q$ and another between $q$ and $r$ we have to do something like
$$f(t) = \begin{cases}
        (1-t)p + tq, & 0\le t\le 1 \\
        (2-t)q + (t-1)r & 1\lt t\le 2     
        \end{cases}$$

We continue in this manner until we include $n$ different cases for the $n$ different segments.

This parameterization is not unique. Nothing says we have to travel along each segment in the same amount of time. We can also rescale the domain so the entire parameterization happens in an interval other than size $n$.

**Update**
If you are writing a computer program and have many points then we don't need a parameterization as above. We can reuse the parameterization of one segment along with a look up table to navigate along the curve.

Store the individual segments as pairs of points in a 0-indexed array. The first segment will be segment $0$ and the $n$th segment will be $n-1$.

At time $t$, $0\le t\lt n$, use the integer part to find the segment and plug the remainder into the formula for a single line segment above. Use the points in the array for $p$ and $q$ in the formula.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a better way to do it then? Each line I have is composed of anywhere between 50-1000 points. I was looking at beziers but I'm not really sure how that would work. Any advice?

Comment: How will the parameterization be used? Do you just want to know where you are at time $t$?

Comment: I wanted to move along the segmented line at equal increments, regardless of the length of the segments. I reckon knowing where I am at time t would work.

Comment: @OmarFarag Please see the update. This is a constant time algorithm that will give you your position on the curve.

Comment: Forgive me if I don't understand your point completely. I understand the pairs of points that represent line segments, however I don't understand your last point, "At time t, 0≤t≤n, use..." What is the integer part? What is the remainder?

Comment: @OmarFarag If $t=2.6$ then the integer part is $2$ so we go to points[2] to get the pair of points corresponding to $p$ and $q$. The integer gives us the segment. Then we plug $0.6$ into $(1-t)p + tq$ to get the point on that segment.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. I sincerely appreciate your help. Thanks :)